# How to handle the correct file path for displaying an image on a web page

Tags: go

I'm struggling with how paths work with http.FileServer.

I have the following code:

server

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("/", homeHandler)
    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:    "127.0.0.1:8080",
        Handler: mux,
    }

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(""))
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static", fs))

    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
```

html

```
<body>
    <img src="static/images/img.jpg" alt="image" style="width:364.5px; height:191.625px;">
</body>
```

I have succeeded in displaying an image on a parsed html template when the html is at root (./index.html) and the image is in a directory at root (./images/img.jpg). But when I try to display it when both are at separate directories at root (./template/index.html, ./images/img.jpg) the implementation fails and the image doesn't show.

I believe there's an important point that I need to handle concerning the paths, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: Use an absolute path to refer to the imagte: `<img src="/static/images/img.jpg">`

Comment: `http.FileServer(http.Dir(""))` Where are the static assets you want to serve?   I didn't see anything in the docs about a sane default if you pass the path `""`.

Comment: @Charlie Tumahai I woudl appreciate if you could point how can this be done. Thanks!

Comment: @erik258 For type Dir it says: An empty Dir is treated as ".". I wanted to set it as root thinking that when the /static/ is stripped it will convert it to ./images/img.jpg

Comment: My comment shows the image tag with the absolute path.  Edit the html to use the text from my comment.